# How i can make a box figure with this alignments as attached?

Tags: framed

I have a framed environment in a double column article. Inside the frame i have some lists i want to display. The problem is that i want the size of the frame to be expanded within the two columns. I tried:

```
    \begin{framed*}
\begin{center}
\begin{itemize}
  \item lala
  \item caca
 \end{itemize}  \captionof{figure}{This is foo.}
  \label{fig:foo}
\end{center}
\end{framed*}
```

But i am getting the following error:

> ! LaTeX Error: Environment framed*
>   undefined.

Comment: please make your code compilable `\documentclass....\begin{document}...\end{document}`

Comment: You want to use a figure caption for an `itemize` list?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{framed}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]
\begin{figure*}
\begin{framed}
\begin{itemize}
\item lala
\item caca
\end{itemize}
\caption{This is foo.}
\label{fig:foo} 
\end{framed}
\end{figure*} 
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I only know of the `framed` environment (without a star). May be this is what your want, obtained with `strip` environment from `cuted`:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{erewhon}
\usepackage{framed, caption}
\usepackage{cuted}
\usepackage{lipsum}%

\begin{document}

\begin{strip}
  \begin{framed}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item lala
      \item caca
    \end{itemize} \captionof{figure}{This is foo.}
    \label{fig:foo}
  \end{framed}
\end{strip}
\lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]